# Problem: Keyframes snapping to the left when moving in graph editor?

Tags: keyframes, graph-editor

[Screen Capture of problem](https://streamable.com/jhm8na)
(don't think I can upload the screen capture here, so I uploaded it to streamable and embedded the link)

This happened spontaneously, and I'm not sure where else to go with this. I've checked all around the program to look for what might have been toggled to cause this issue, but to no avail. The keyframes simply snap to some portion of the graph editor over to the left when I press 'g' or drag them. Any help or clarity is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: you can share them here if you convert it to .gif before

Comment: It looks like a snap to a non-existent marker, when 'snap to marker' is not set  :( . Try a getaround  ..   1. Marker > add marker.  2. 'A' in the marker region to 'select all' markers, and 'X' to delete markers?